# Windows Phone get image source path in String

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get image source path in string but not able to get it.

Here is my code

```
String tempJPEG = imgUpload.Source.ToString() ;
```

Here **imgUpload** is `<Image x:Name="imgUpload" ></Image>`

I am getting this `"System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage"` in **tempJPEG**.

How can I get image path?

Answer (score 1):

The source property of the image control contains BitmapImage itself. Therefore you need to use the BitmapImage.UriSource property.